# What is the best way to separate a large html file into three smaller html files?

Tags: html, code-organization

I have a very large website, and I was wondering how to separate a single HTML file into 3 separate HTML files. In order, to organize the code as individual components of a whole like this:

```
Header.html

Body.html

Footer.html
```

How can I break the html code into three separate html files but still make them work together as a whole?

Comment: This question is insanely broad...

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and copy segments of its contents into other files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A straightforward method would be to use PHP to concatenate 3 includes:

**Step 1)** In your .htaccess file, enable your server to parse `.html` & `.htm` files as `.php` files:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

**Step 2)** In `page.html`, write (only) the following:

```
<?php

include '/home/example/public_html/header.html';
include '/home/example/public_html/body.html';
include '/home/example/public_html/footer.html';

?>
```

**N.B.** `/home/example/public_html/` is an example relative-to-root server path. You'll need to change this to whatever your own relative-to-root server path is.

Now, when you point your browser at `page.html`, your server will parse that `.html` file as a `.php` file and concatenate and deliver three separate PHP server-side include files as a single `.html` file.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you're dead-set on static html code in my answer.  The answers on switching to dynamic pages are far better.

That said, if I've understood your question, you're looking for something like this:

http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/