# How can I load a separate html page into my main index.html? I imagine it can be done by selecting an element id with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Right now I am planning on using this on every page, but it is not loading the nav and I'm not sure why.

```
<!-- This is in my main HTML that I want nav in-->
    <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
    
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("NavBar.html");
    });
    </script>

<!-- this is the NavBar.html file-->
<header>
<div class="header-row">
            <div class="header-column d-lg-none">
                <div class="header-row">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-semibold text-7 mb-0">
                        <a href="index.html" class="
              text-decoration-none text-color-light
              custom-primary-font
            ">Dynamic</a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: What's the question? People use `load` all the time. jQuery didn't add it for giggles. If you're looking for opinions on its utility, that's off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question it's not working

Comment: Use the `complete` function argument to be told when the load completes. See [the documentation for more](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1):

it's not a terrible practice, depending on what components you are going to use inside this method. E.g., Navbars and footers, no problem.

Have a look on this question: [How to separate html text file into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238131/how-to-separate-html-text-file-into-multiple-files)

Comment: Thank you very much I tried this, but it didn't work I don't know if there is something wrong with my NavBar file that makes it not insert properly.

Comment: Well, aparently you cannot embed both files if they are local on your pc. I tried it and got CORS error. Check out what this guy is saying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht/20578692#20578692.