# Get text between two tags using substringBetween() method of StringUtils

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I have an input like:

```xml
<address>
    <addressLine>280 Flinders Mall</addressLine>
    <geoCodeGranularity>PROPERTY</geoCodeGranularity>
</address>
<address type="office">
    <addressLine>IT Park</addressLine>
    <geoCodeGranularity>office Space</geoCodeGranularity>
</address>
```

I want to capture everything between the address tag.

I tried:

```java
File file = new File("test.html");
String testHtml = FileUtils.readFileToString(file); 
String title = StringUtils.substringBetween(testHtml, "<address>", "</address>");
```

This does not work for all the cases because the address tag may contain some attribute inside. Please help how to get text for such string.

Comment: You should use an XPath parser here, rather than using a string or regex library.

Comment: The file is so big that I cannot use Parser due to performance issue. So, I tries using a regex or Java library like StringUtils.

Comment: What does your expected output look like, and what _is_ it?  Is it a file, a string, something else?

Comment: The final goal is to get the count of all characters between address tag. So i tried to fetch the string output from StringUtils and then find its count. Please correct me if I am going in wrong track. I know Parser is the best method to achieve this. But I am not allowed to use parser due to performance issue.

Comment: So you want a _single_ number here, for the count of _all_ characters between _any_ `<address>` tag?  Is that right?

Comment: yes thats the exact requirement.

Comment: Do you want to count whitespace (e.g. space) characters?  Or do you only want to count alphas?

Comment: You can convert file into String and then find it. Check below Answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen everything including whitepaces and newline etc.

Comment: Convert the substring to XML and parse as you want. You will have a small XML to parse and you would be able to do treat it like XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the file into String and can determine the start and end index of the desired sub-string as below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Address {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Complete File Path
        File dir =
            new File("\\..\\..\\Test.html");

        // Convert File Data As String
        String data =
            new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths
                    .get(dir
                        .getAbsolutePath())));

        // For Loop to get all the <address> tags in the file.
        for (int index = data.indexOf("<address"); index >= 0;) {

            // Start Index
            int startIndex = data.indexOf(">", index + 1);
            ++startIndex;

            // End Index
            int indexOfEnd = data.indexOf("</address>", startIndex + 1);

            String attributesString = data.substring(startIndex, indexOfEnd);
            // Replace below line with desired logic with calling trim() on the String attributesString
            System.out.println(attributesString);

            // Next Address will be after the end of first address
            index = data.indexOf("<address", indexOfEnd + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. but my file size is 102 MB. Is it a good idea to convert file data into a single string?

Comment: What is the frequency of the execution?

Comment: it executes once in a day.

Comment: Then I believe it's ok to do that, as soon as you are out the method Java GC will take care of it. But do consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have post as well.

Comment: I am getting this error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Instead of converting the entire file into a single string, Is it possible to capture just the address tag and store it in one string?

Comment: It is going out of memory while converting of File to String? Or after that in sub-sequent processes?

Comment: while converting file to String. This is because my file is too big. Can we store only <address>..text..</address> in string? instead of converting entire file into 1 string? I am not sure how to achieve this. But the idea is to take out only address tags from the file and then store in single string.

Comment: Do you have the option to increase the JVM heap size? By the time I am thinking through the way if we can break the file.

Comment: Can you split your html file as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551409/what-is-the-best-way-to-separate-a-large-html-file-into-three-smaller-html-files into sub files? So that you can process it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should *not* use regex to parse HTML/XML content.  Instead, use a parser like XPath.  Given that you seem to not be able to use a parser, we can try the following option using a pattern matcher:

```
int count = 0;
String input = "<address>\n<addressLine>280 Flinders Mall</addressLine>\n    <geoCodeGranularity>PROPERTY</geoCodeGranularity>\n</address>\n<address type=\"office\">\n    <addressLine>IT Park</addressLine>\n    <geoCodeGranularity>office Space</geoCodeGranularity>\n</address>";
String pattern = "<address[^>]*>(.*?)</address>";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

while (m.find( )) {
    count += m.group(1).length();
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
}

System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

This finds a count of 198 for the two `<address>` tags in your sample data.

To make this work with a `BufferedReader` you might have to ensure that you read in one complete `<address>` tag at a time.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. This works for a single input string as you have written in the answer. But this does not work when I try to read my input file through buffer reader.

Comment: Read in one `<address>` tag at a time.  Then use my answer, and rollover the remaining content to capture the next `<address>` tag.

Comment: I am so sorry i did not understand your last reply. I am very new to java I/O.

Comment: If the issue is that my answer only works if you have a string with a complete `<address>` tag with closing tag, then the solution is to keep reading until you find an opening and closing tag.  So you'll have to do a bit of parsing work.

Comment: Is it possible to read in one <address> tag at a time in java? I know we can read the entire file line by line using BufferedReader and readLine().

Comment: Well this is perhaps the tricky part.  You may read line by line until you have consumed some number of complete `<address>` tags.  Then, use my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

        parser = scan.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(parser);
        if (parser.equals("<adress>")) {
            parser = scan.nextLine();
            // System.out.println(parser);
            int startPosition = parser.indexOf("<adressLine>") + "<adressLine>".length();
            int endPosition = parser.indexOf("</adressLine>", startPosition);
            idNumber = parser.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
            parser = scan.nextLine();

            int startPosition1 = parser.indexOf("<geoCodeGranularity>") + "<geoCodeGranularity>".length();
            int endPosition1 = parser.indexOf("</geoCodeGranularity>", startPosition1);
            time = parser.substring(startPosition1, endPosition1);
            parser = scan.nextLine();
```

......
Algorithm must be like this. If you read on file.